# Are poker questions referencing specific hands too subjective for the site?

Tags: discussion

I learned to play poker by asking and pontificating on specific hand histories posted on other forums and talked about with friends.  For any but the most basic decisions, poker is often clouded by so much metagame as to make a single "right answer" impossible.  I am for poker discussion here as opposed to the area51 poker proposal, so I ask my question here.

Example post to get an idea:
I am playing a no-limit cash game of Texas holdem with blinds of $1-$2 at a 7 handed table where everyone is about 100 big blinds deep.  An aggressive losing player opens to 12 on the button, and it folds to me with JJ in the big blind.  Ive been here for about an hour, but quiet, and havent played with this gentleman before.  Is 3-betting or calling better, and why?  What is the correct plan for dangerous flops?

Answer (score 2):

**I think you should ask your question on the site,** vetting questions on meta prior to seeing how they actually play out on the main site isn't the best plan as far fewer people will see it here. I think it would be a slightly better fit with a bit of generalization.  Something like:

"What do I need to call/raise an aggressive player who makes a strong opening bid?" as a subject and then use your full question text.  This gives room for people to give strong general tactical advice while addressing your specific question as well.  I play poker but I'm not deep enough into the tournament scene to know if opening to 12 is critical to the question, or could be generalized.  My gut tells me that could be generalized a bit as well.

I would prefer not to see 3 questions that differ only in that the players hand is tens/jacks/queens.  Let's see if we can answer your question while answering the broader case as well.